# Installing minikube on my windows also chocolately

Tags: windows, docker, kubernetes, minikube, chocolatey

**Material that i used**

- -window 10
- installed chocolate on C:\WINDOWS\system32> and installed choco install minikube.
- docker(individual)
- i used the website(https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-minikube/)

**situation**

- I could not install chocolatey on my local(C:\Users\taiga>) that's why I installed the choco as an administrator(C:\WINDOWS\system32>).

**what do I want to do?**

- I want to use the minikube on my local(C:\Users\taiga>) not on the C:\WINDOWS\system32> which started as the administrator.

screenshot 
1. installing was a success
[image]

2.I tried to  kubectl version and command not found why ?
[image]

Do you have a solution that is able to use kubnets on my local, not on administrator ?

Comment: strange question, can you please describe your need, why you want to install minikube like this, although you have to give admin rights later on to minikube utmost every place

Comment: Does this help? https://superuser.com/q/1095475/134834 . Also, have you tried installing Minikube standalone (not via chocolatey)? Maybe you can choose it's installation path that way.